# Validating form input with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Hi. I have a form that I am using for a google map page and I want to limit the input field to allow only `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, spaces and hyphens. I was using:

```
var postCode = $('#form').val();
Validate = /[a-z0-9 A-Z\-]$/.test(postCode);

if (!Validate) {
    $('#results').html("Please enter alpha numeric (a-z 0-9) characters");
    return;
}
```

but that doesn't work. Could someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `/^[a-z0-9 A-Z\-]*$/`. Note `^` in the beginning of the string - together with `$` at the end it ensures that you validate the whole string and not only its suffix.

If you don't want to accept empty string you can replace `*` (zero or more quantifier) with `+` (one or more) or even specify exact range for length like that: `/^[a-z0-9 A-Z\-]{3,10}$/`.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I needed, I didn't even think about the 0 char entry so that's an added bonus, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+([ -][0-9a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

Matches:

> 90210
>
> abcDEF
>
> abc DEF
>
> abc-DEF
>
> a1b-2c3

But does not match if a leading or trailing space/hyphen is present.

Based on: http://regexpal.com/